# How to have different title and tab title in vim

Tags: vim, tabs, header, terminal, title

As of now I have put the following in my .vimrc file in order to display the name of the currently open file in the screen title of my Terminal:

```
autocmd BufEnter * let &titlestring = expand("%:@")
set title
```

Is it possible to also set a specific tab title? That is, when I have a number of vim tabs open in Terminal on my Mac I would Terminal to display the directory path in the Terminal header when I have selected the tab related to the file and I would like to display only the name of the file in the header of the tab.

Answer (score 8):

### Some comments to your goal

Personally I hardly use tabs in vim. What you want to have can be achieved by setting some options. Before I talk about the options, I would say that what you want to do could be inconvenient. Because in vim, tab is a collection of windows, which means, it can have splitted windows, and in a tab page, you can show more than one buffers. That is, in a tab page, it is not always showing one file. As you are switching from split to split in a tab page, both your terminal title **and** the tab label could be changing.

For example, you have 3 dirs, `/one /two and /three` and two tab pages in your vim.

Now you have:

```
tab1:
/one/file1

tab2 (in split-windows):
/one/file1
/two/file1
/three/file1
```

When you are in `tab1`, your terminal title would be `/one`, tab1-label would be `file1`, fine. But when you are in tab2, your terminal title will change as you are switching from split to split. In this example, the tab-label would be same `file1`, so you have to check terminal window **and** the tab label to know which buffer/file you are currently editing. I don't think this is convenient.

### Answer to your question

Okay, if you want that to happen, `:h setting-tabline` and check the example in the help text, it shows how to set the label of tabs. This should achieve your goal for vim in Terminal.

FYI, to get only parent dir name you can use `%:p:h`. to get only filename, you can use `%:p:t`.

Plus, some other things you may want to check:

- There is another autocommand event: `TabEnter` .
- `:h setting-tabline` if you want your tabline to show some complex text or other highlighting
- if you want to play with filename/dirname further, you can check `:h expand()` and `:h filename-modifiers`

Comment: Actually, I meant Terminal tabs - not Vim tabs. I would like to be able to assign different titles to Terminal tabs and the Terminal header when some Terminal tab is selected. But thank you for your reply!

Comment: Then this is not a task for vim. @user2898925 if you have found the command how to change the (terminal)tab-label in your terminal outside vim. In vim you can invoke that command to do the change. check the help of your terminal program please. BTW, if you meant terminal tabs, how come `a number of vim tabs open`? also if the tabs you meant were terminal tabs, why you open so many vim instance? You can open many files in one vim instance, and it makes editing easier. e.g. copy/paste between files etc.